# KAFKA WARNING :- Offset commit failed on partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Team,  I get the below WARNING and NOT ERROR

```
{"timestamp":"2023-08-23 09:36:43.300 UTC","level":"WARN","thread":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#7-0-C-1","logger":"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-p-worker-27, groupId=p-worker] Offset commit failed on partition p-topic-name at offset 65605: The request timed out.","context":"default","dd.service":"p-worker"}
```

I see a no of stackoverflow questions and answers relating to the above but they are all about ERRORS and not WARNINGS

I checked the Kafka code and I could see the below

```
if (error.exception() instanceof RetriableException) {
                            log.warn("Offset commit failed on partition {} at offset {}: {}", tp, offset, error.message());
                        } else {
                            log.error("Offset commit failed on partition {} at offset {}: {}", tp, offset, error.message());
                        }
```

Does this mean the error was retriable and Kafka retried it and was successful and does this mean I do not have to worry about it?

Any leads are appreciated guys. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide more logs for us to know if there actually was a retry. For example, the log could be printed and your JVM/computer could have immediately crashed, so there'd be no commit

Comment: @OneCricketeer I see the below in the logs


[Consumer clientId=consumer-p-worker-50, groupId=p-worker] Group coordinator b-2.hay-kafka-l-clust.x7pgku.c4.kafka.es-west-2.amazonaws.com:9094 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: error response REQUEST_TIMED_OUT. isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.

[Consumer clientId=consumer-p-worker-50, groupId=p-worker] Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator b-2.hay-kafka-l-clust.x7pgku.c4.kafka.es-west-2.amazonaws.com:9094 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)

Comment: Sorry unable to format it but when I looked at the kafka code it pretty much looks like it went thru  markCoordinatorUnknown(error); method in class AbstractCoordinator.java

Comment: Okay, that's a retry but not directly related to consumer offset commits

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank u. So do you think the offsets are not commited? I am going to check in my log if the same message has appeared again for processing. It is slightly tricky though. Will give it a go.

Comment: You can run `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` command to check what offsets are being committed, or not but if the Group coordinator is failing  and timing out, then I think its possible no offsets would get committed until that is healthy